# Can Geo Nodes Read An Excel File

Tags: geometry-nodes

Can Geo Nodes read an Excel file?  Similar to what Sverchok can do https://youtu.be/Q_2oiTTZHOI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple answer: no, this is not possible directly.

You should get the data before using the geometry nodes.

PS: I've not tested that, but looking at the [documentation](http://nortikin.github.io/sverchok/docs/nodes/viz/geo_nodes_viewer.html#geo-nodes-viewer), it seems possible to combine the two.